# calculations with floats in a txt file

Tags: python

I have a txt file that is composed of three columns, the first column is integers and the second and third column are floats.  I want to do a calculation with each float and separate by line.  My pseudocode is below:

```
def first_function(file):
    pogt = 0.   
    f=open(file, 'r')
    for line in f:
        pogt += otherFunction(first float, second float)
        f.close
```

Also, would the "for line in f" guarantee that my pogt will be the sum of my otherFunction calculation of all the lines in the txt file?

Comment: my question is how to get the first float and second float into my other function

Comment: You need to give more information as in how your text is defined. Are the numbers separated by spaces? Like this: `18 3.14 2.17`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you get the values for `first float` and `second float` correctly, your code is close to correct, you'll need to dedent (the inverse of indent) the `f.close` line, or even better, use `with`, it will handle the close for you (btw, you should do `f.close()` instead of `f.close`)

And do not use `file` as variable name, it's reserved word in Python.

Also use better names for your variables.

Assuming your file is separated by spaces, you can define `get_numbers` as follows:

```
def get_numbers(line):
    [the_integer, first_float, second_float] = line.strip().split()
    return (first_float, second_float)

def first_function(filename):
    the_result = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            (first_float, second_float) = get_numbers(line)
            the_result += other_function(first_float, second_float)
```

Comment: note that `f.close` won't do anything anyway unless you call it

Comment: Yap, since I change the code to using `with`, I forgot to include that point. Thanks, Eevee!

Comment: I'm getting NameError: global name 'get_numbers' is not defined

Comment: `get_numbers` should be your defined function to get the numbers from the line. I suppose you already have that function? If not, please answer my question on how the file is formatted. I've guessed the definition of `get_numbers`.

Comment: I got it; I'm using
    `floats = line.split()` 
and then accessing the first float by using `floats[1]` and then the second float in the line using `floats[2]` and keep your line `the_result += other_function(floats[1], floats[2])`

Comment: Yap. That's exactly what my method is doing.